# ibdata1 file size still increases, after adding innodb_file_per_table=1 and deleting ibdata1 file

Tags: mariadb, innodb, ibdata

MariaDB
ibdata1 file is increasing in size significantly.
Even after deleting the ibdata1 file and adding the

**innodb_file_per_table=1**
in my.cnf file.

ibdata1 is again consuming the space and exhausting the disk space.
Advise any change or suggestion

Comment: If you've deleted ibdata1 you've lost your data. There where [some bug reports](https://jira.mariadb.org) but they have been fixed in a newer MariaDB versions. After you restore from your backup, try a newer MariaDB of the same Major.Minor version but different patch version. The latest version is getting finalized today.

Comment: The data was restored from the backup took before deleting the ibdata1 file.  DBs are running fine, except that the ibdata1 file is consuming space with same pace.

Comment: If you look closely at the [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb), you'll rarely see "you can just delete X file because its not important" and never around `ibdata1`. What MariaDB version? Example bug that has been since fixed about file size growing - [MDEV-31234](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31234) - note the fixedVersion and ensure you have a version of that or newer.

Comment: Do you happen to have long active transactions? Can you check your history list length from `show engine innodb status\G` statement?

Comment: @jerichorivera yes, we do have long active transactions. History list length is below:
History list length `98318806`

Comment: Then look into this - https://www.percona.com/blog/why-is-the-ibdata1-file-continuously-growing-in-mysql/ - basically you want to avoid long running transactions eg enable autocommit, close unused connections, check pool connections if you use it.